# ActionFunction doesn't seem to fire

Tags: visualforce, javascript, actionfunction

I have a method in my controller class that supposed to parse a string and then save the values to an object.

```
public void updateUserPreferences(String preferences) {
        System.debug(preferences);
        List<String> splitPrefs = preferences.split(',');
        System.debug(splitPrefs);
        for (String prefPair : splitPrefs) {
            List<String> prefs = prefPair.split(':');
            userPref.put(prefs[0], Boolean.valueOf(prefs[1]));
        }
        System.debug(userPref);
    }
    
    public void saveUserPreferences() {
        updateUserPreferences(Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('preferences'));
        upsert userPref;
    }
```

Whenever this code is triggered none of the debug statements run and no log is outputted, which is part of the reason I think that it's not firing properly.

It's called in the vfpage by this

```
function updatePreferences() {
     let retStr = ''
     let checkBoxes = $('[type$=checkbox]');
     for (let i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
          let box = checkBoxes.get(i);
          let checkd = box.hasAttribute("checked") ? "true" : "false"
          retStr += box.getAttribute("class") + ":" + checkd;
          if (i != checkBoxes.length - 1) retStr += ',';
     }
     return retStr;
}

function savePrefsEdit() {
     saveUserPrefs(updatePreferences());
     hidePrefsBlock();
 }

<apex:pageMessages showDetail="true" id="errors"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="saveUserPrefs" action="{!saveUserPreferences}" rerender="errors">
     <apex:param name="preferences" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

No matter what happens, the object is never saved / updated. If I add the onComplete attribute to the action function with just a printout that runs successfully, but there's no change to the object itself. Any help would be extremely appreciated. This is my first time working with action functions so I have a sneaking suspicion it's somehow related to my implementation. Thanks in advance for any help!

------Edit------
Adding screenshot of my log level settings
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using CurrentPage, which, if I recall, acts weird in some cases, you'll want to just assign the variable directly to an Apex property:

```
public transient String preferences { get; set; }
public void saveUserPreferences() {
  updateUserPreferences(preferences);
  upsert userPref;
}
```

Here, we make the string transient so it does not persist in the view state, valid for one transaction only.

Next, we assign it within the parameter:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="saveUserPrefs" action="{!saveUserPreferences}" rerender="errors">
  <apex:param name="preferences" value="" assignTo="{!preferences}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

This gets rid of the complex part. Finally, I'd suggest that you could probably switch to proper JSON so it looks nicer. First, change from a String to a Map:

```
public transient Map<String, Boolean> preferences { get; set; }
```

And in your JavaScript, use an Object:

```
function updatePreferences() {
  return Object.fromEntries(
    [...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')].map((element) => [
      element.getAttribute("class"),
      element.getAttribute("checked"),
    ])
  );
}
```

Which would return something like:

```
{
   "userPref1": true,
   "userPref2": false,
   "userPref3": false
}
```

Which you can then parse without all the weird splits and stuff:

```
for(String prefName: preferences.keySet()) {
  userPref.put(prefName, preferences.get(prefName));
}
```

Comment: This is amazing thank you so much! Clearly I still have a lot to learn for javascript development. Unfortunately I've implemented the changes and still having the same issue. I'm going to edit the question to have my log levels setup in case that's the issue. It's definitely running on the javascript side, I can see it's generating the proper JSON, I just can't tell if it's erroring out on the controller. I also added  an ApexPages.addMessage to the saveUserPreferences method but it didn't show up on the page.

Comment: @RonocEroom I'll mobile, but I can write up a quick demo when I get home tonight.

Comment: As an update, I added a commandButton to directly link to the save method in the controller, then added a debug command there and it still did not appear to run. Not sure if that means anything but it seems like there's some level of disconnect in running the actions from the page.

Comment: Realized I forgot to tag @sfdcfox